# Averaging column 2D array python

Tags: python, arrays, list, average, multidimensional-array

I have a 2D arraylist data which fills with a loop like this:

```
data.append([TrueID,rssi])
```

after 8 times i got this value for data:

```
data =

    [['469420270013002A', -90], 
     ['469420270005000C', -89], 
     ['469420270013002A', -94], 
     ['4694202700270003', -53], 
     ['469420270005000C', -91], 
     ['469420270013002A', -92], 
     ['4694202700270003', -55]]
```

I want to calculate the average RSSI value of each TrueID and return the lowest RSSI value with its TrueID.

So I need output:

```
print "The weakest ID is " ID_result " with Rssi value of " rssi_result
>>The weakest ID is '4694202700270003' with Rssi value of -54
```

It's necessary the 2D array fills until 20 values and continues like a FIFO system.

All suggestions are welcome (even if you know other methods to get to the same result)!

Thank you!

Comment: `-54` is actually going to be the maximum  value here.

Comment: Please provide example code of what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`collections.defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) and `max`:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict                                   
>>> lis = [['469420270013002A', -90],                                 
     ['469420270005000C', -89], 
     ['469420270013002A', -94], 
     ['4694202700270003', -53], 
     ['469420270005000C', -91], 
     ['469420270013002A', -92], 
     ['4694202700270003', -55]]
>>> d = defaultdict(list)                
>>> for k, v in lis:                                                      
    d[k].append(v)
...
```

Now `d` contains:

```
>>> d
defaultdict(<type 'list'>,
{'469420270005000C': [-89, -91],
 '4694202700270003': [-53, -55],
 '469420270013002A': [-90, -94, -92]})
```

Now use `max` and a dict comprehension to calculate the average and find out the max (key, value) pair:

```
>>> max({k:sum(v)/float(len(v)) for k, v in d.items()}.items(), key=lambda x:x[1])
('4694202700270003', -54.0)
```

Comment: Thank you Ashwini Chaudhary! It works like u said, 1 more thing: How to do after 20 values overwrite the original values like a fifo system ?

Comment: @user3055369 Use [`collections.deque`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque) with `maxlen=20`, to get a FIFO system.

Comment: I solved this by using append and pop:         `lis.append([TrueID,rssi])

        d2counter += 1

        if d2counter >= 20:

            lis.pop(0)`